# What is the explicit formula for the n-th term of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have watched some videos on YouTube on finding an explicit formula from a recursive sequence but none of the tricks they have shown seem to work in my case. I have the recursive relation defined as $a_n = (1-a_{n-1})f(n-1)$ where $f(n)=\tfrac{1555+3n}{1612535}$ and $a_0=0$. (I'm not replacing $f(n-1)$ by $\tfrac{1552+3n}{1612535}$) because it gets messy). I want to find the general formula for the n-th term. I think i found a solution but no calculator is able to calculate it and im not even sure if it's true or not. Here is my thought process:

$$a_n = (1-a_{n-1})f(n-1)$$
$$a_n = f(n-1)-(a_{n-1})f(n-1)$$
$$a_n = f(n-1)-(f(n-1))(f(n-2))+(a_{\mathbf{n-2}})(f(n-1))(f(n-2))$$
$$a_n = f(n-1)-(f(n-1))(f(n-2))+(f(n-1))(f(n-2))(f(n-3))-(a_{\mathbf{n-3}})(f(n-1))(f(n-2))(f(n-3))$$

Seeing the term with $a_n$ only appears in the last term and $a_0=0$, $a_0$ will cancel it. So i have come to the conclusion that:

$$a_n = f(n-1)-(f(n-1))(f(n-2))+(f(n-1))(f(n-2))(f(n-3))\cdots \pm f(n-1) \cdots f(1)$$

After that, i cleaned things up a bit:
$$a_n =\prod_{i=1}^{1}f(n-i)-\prod_{i=1}^{2}f(n-i)+\prod_{i=1}^{3}f(n-i) \cdots \pm\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(n-i)$$
$$a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}((-1)^{k+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(f(n-i))))$$

The $(-1)^{k+1}$ part is to determine the $\pm$.

So far, i am unsure if i made any mistakes while clearing things up a bit, since the product and sum notations are sometimes difficult to implement.

Even if i didn't made any mistakes, no calculator is able to calculate this expression.

I wonder if there is an easier way to find the formula for the n-th term of the series without using the product and sum notations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think that there exists an explicit formula ? Most sequences haven't such a formula...

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't know actually. I have never thought about that possibility. Thanks.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Done and amazing !

Answer (score 2):

*Looking at the sequence you properly wrote, it is almost sure that the incomplete gamma function would appear somewhere.*

Making the problem more general
$$a_n = (1-a_{n-1})\,f_{n-1}\qquad \text{with} \qquad f_n=\alpha+\beta\, n$$ with $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$.

I shall skip the intermediate steps which are quite tedious. The result is :
$$\color{blue}{a_n=\frac{e^{-1/\beta }\,\, (-\beta )^{\frac{\alpha }{\beta
   }+n-2}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{\beta }\right)}\,\,\, \Delta_n}$$ where
$$\color{blue}{\Delta_n=(\beta -\alpha )\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha-\beta }{\beta
   },-\frac{1}{\beta }\right)\,\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{\alpha
   }{\beta }\right)+}$$ $$\color{blue}{ (\alpha +\beta  (n-1))\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{\beta }\right)\,\,
   \Gamma \left(n+\frac{\alpha -\beta}{\beta},-\frac{1}{\beta }\right)}$$

For your specific case, make $\alpha=\frac{1}{1037}$ and $\beta=\frac{3}{1612535}$ to have an almost linear function with an asymptotic slope $\sim 1.79\times 10^{-6}$.

The problem is not more difficult for $a_0 \neq 0$.

We also have an explicit solution if $f_n=\alpha+\beta\, n+\gamma\,n^2$ but in terms of the $\, _1F_2(.)$ generalized hypergeometric function.